# GraphQL with API Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, api-gateway, google-cloud-api-gateway

Team,

I was an evaluating architecture and it seems that the architecture plans to have a BFF like GraphQL sitting before API Gateway like APIGEE. Just to add, the backend microservices are written in Spring Boot.

Does it make sense to have both BFF and APIGEE? Is there anything that can't be handled via GraphQL which has to be taken care of by the API Gateway?

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 2):

In case you missed that API Gateway is now available: https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/about-api-gateway

I am also currently running a Cloud Run service (kotlin/spring-boot) with a GraphQL endpoint and will try to bring it together with the API Gateway (beta)